# How to populate data in a table using foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have the following data in a field named `materiaal` in db

```
{
 "1":{"'aantal'":"sdfsd","'artikelnummer'":"sdfds","'omschri'":"sdfdsf"},
 "2":{"'aantal'":"sdfdsf","'artikelnummer'":"dsfsdf","'omschri'":"dsfsdf"},
 "3":{"'aantal'":"sdfds","'artikelnummer'":"sdfsdf","'omschri'":"dsfsd"}
}
```

I want it to display in a table having fields like `aantal`,`artikelnummer` and so on. As there are 3 values of materiaal in the db, so the table must have 3 rows. How can I display the table using *foreach loop*.

I'm getting the values using `{{{$werkbon_report->materiaal}}}`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a seed file in `app/database/seeds`:

```
<?php

class PostTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('posts')->truncate();

        foreach(range(1,3) as $index)
        {
            DB::table('posts')->insert(['colum1' => 'value1', 'colum2' => 'value2',]);
        }

    }

}
```

Add a call for it in `app/database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php`:

```
$this->call('PostTableSeeder');
```

And seed your database:

```
php artisan db:seed
```

Answer (score 0):

From example you provided `materiaal` field contains JSON encoded array of kev/value pairs.
First, you need to decode them and itterate them.
Try this in your view file

```
@foreach(json_decode($werkbon_report->materiaal) as $row)
    @foreach($row as $item => $value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $item }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

PS: this problem is not Laravel related ;)